# Can a simple multi-dimensional array dereference be slow?

Tags: c++, pointers, gprof

I'm struggling to understand the output I'm getting from **gprof**.

I have a simple wrapper class around a 2D array that I need to be contiguous in memory.

Its constructor and the method I use to access values are:

```
Array2d::Array2d(int size, double initialValue)
: mSize(size) {
    data = new double *[size];
    data[0] = new double[size * size];

    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        data[i] = data[0] + i * size;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            data[i][j] = initialValue;
        }
    }
}


double &Array2d::operator()(int i, int j) {
    return data[i][j];
}
```

In the numerical code I'm working on, this is one output I obtained from gprof:

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 49.33     34.80    34.80 43507867293     0.00     0.00  Array2d::operator()(int, int)
 18.05     47.53    12.73                             jacobi(Array2d&, Array2d&, int, int, double, double, double, int)
```

I'm surprised to see that almost 50% of the running time is spent accessing values from the array.

This Array2d class replaced the use of `std::vector<double>`, which was much faster.

What I am failing to understand here?

Comment: Why are you using more than one pointer ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in that part of the code? It's not because your function is called 43 billion times? (In little under 35 seconds in total)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: The array initialization is _super wierd_, but I _think_ it may actually be valid.  There is a block of memory for all of the elements contiguously, and each element in `data` points to a "row", `size` apart.  Bizarre, but it should work.

Comment: That's not a multi-dimensional array (an array of arrays). Its an array of pointers to arrays; they're not synonymous. the former can be *very* cache friendly; the latter not-so-much. But at least the backdrop is contiguous, so there's hope.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yep, hadn't seen that kind of thing for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm surprised to see that almost 50% of the running time is spent
>   accessing values from the array.

We cannot say much about this without seeing your code. It is easily possible to write code that has higher percentage of a single call. Consider

```
int main() { 
    while(true){ 
        foo(); 
    }
}
```

A profiler will tell you that close to 100% of the runtime is spend in `foo`. Does that mean `foo` is slow? No, we dont know.

The percentages you get from the profiler rather give you a hint to where the hot spots are in your code. If you know that 50% of the time is spend in one particular function call, then you know that this is a good canditate for improving performance. If you optimize this one function call you can achieve a speedup of up to x2 (cf [amdahls law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)).

On the other hand, a function that uses only 0.1% of the total runtime can be made 1000-times faster without a significant impact on the total runtime.

Whether your element access is slow or fast, you can only know if you implement a second variant, leave everything else in the code as is and repeat the profiling. The variant that leads to a higher percentage performs worse.